# Checkout form validation class if passed

Tags: magento2, checkout, form-validation

I'd like to add a CSS class to form inputs in checkout when they passed the validation.

Currently an *error* class appears when validation fails, I just want to add a *passed* class when validation is OK, or maybe find a way to differenciate not yet filled fields from validated fields.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there is a better way to do that, but I ended up putting a Magento JS mixin to override the validate function of Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract

in requirejs-config.js

```
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract': {
            'Vendor_Module/js/form/element/abstract-mixin': true
        }
    }
}
```

and in Vendor_Module/js/form/element/abstract-mixin.js

```
define([], function () {
'use strict';
return function (targetModule) {
    //if targetModule is a uiClass based object
    return targetModule.extend({
        validate: function () {
            var result = this._super(); //call parent method
            if (result.valid) {
                $('#' + result.target.uid).addClass('_valid');
            }
            return result;
        }
    });
};
```

});

I'd have liked to find something prettier, but I find knockout very confusing in the checkout and I can't spend that much time to simply add a CSS class...